# Parsing through json data for aws sns event data in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I was able to assign the sns event data to a variable using

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    print("From SNS: " + message)
```

Output :

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventVersion": "2.0",
            "eventSource": "aXXXX",
            "awsRegion": "XXXXX",
            "eventTime": "2016-03-09T12:24:19.255Z",
            "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
            "userIdentity": {
                "principalId": "AWS:XXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "requestParameters": {
                "sourceIPAddress": "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
            },
            "responseElements": {
                "x-amz-request-id": "XXXX",
                "x-amz-id-2": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "s3": {
                "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
                "configurationId": "xxx-xxx-xxx",
                "bucket": {
                    "name": "bucketname",
                    "ownerIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "XXXXXX"
                    },
                    "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxx"
                },
                "object": {
                    "key": "index.js",
                    "size": 7068,
                    "eTag": "xxxx",
                    "sequencer": "0000000000"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unable to further parse and get the values of `awsRegion`, `Records.s3.bucket.name` and `Records.s3.object.key`.

I have tried `bucketname = message['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']`.
getting the error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Don't you need to access `event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']`, not `message['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you may need to load the json:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    parsed_message = json.loads(message)
    print(parsed_message['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'])
```

Gives me

```
u'bucketname'
```

Or are you doing the loads somewhere outside your function?

Comment: no , I am loading inside the function,my question is how can i further parse through the values stored in message

Comment: I think the message is still a string - hence your error mentioning String indices. I was thinking you have parsed the outer json, but that this message is still a string and needs loads'ing. The ['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'] lookup works fine for me when I loads the json string you have included in your question.

Comment: My python interpreter prints parsed json out far less prettily too, which further makes me believe that message is still a string at the point you print it out in your code. We could be running different versions of python though which might account for that?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 , below code  actualy worked for me 
`def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    parsed_message = json.loads(message)
    bucket = parsed_message['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'] `
    print ("BUCKET :" + bucket)

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same thing in node.js.  I mistakenly assumed the event was passing JSON and not a string.  I added:

```
var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
console.log('Message received from SNS:', message);
var bleh=JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
var blah = bleh.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
console.log('Bucket Name:', blah);
```

which finally kicked out the right bucket name.